# Questions about academia in economics

Tags: discussion

I just posted the [following question over at Academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/61529/visiting-professor-opportunities-for-phd-candidates):

> **Visiting professor opportunities for PhD candidates**
>
> In my field, economics, I occasionally see opportunities for ABD PhD
> Candidates to apply for one- or two-semester visiting professor
> positions (presumably as sabbatical cover). I have only ever heard of
> two such opportunities, and each was through an email forwarded by our
> graduate adviser. Are these positions advertised centrally anywhere?

I think thematically it definitely makes sense over at Academia, but I can't help but wonder whether it would get better answers in this community, given that I suspect the answer is probably field-specific. Would the question be appropriate at Economics.SE? And, separate but not unrelated, where do you think it would get better answers?

Comment: FYI -- somebody on Academia.SE did point out that a lot of these positions are listed on AEA, which makes sense but was still surprising to me. So I do have a good answer to the question itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would not consider such questions on topic here. They are about professional prospects related to the Economics discipline, not about the content of the Economics discipline itself, which is the purpose of economics.se as I understand it.

Comment: I share your opinion and have accepted your answer. Dissenters, if they exist, are still welcome to chime in.

Answer (score 0):

I think that these types of questions are well suited for this site: http://www.econjobrumors.com/.